# Set input value with text in link with javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I have an input field `<input type="text" name="input">`.

I also have some links:

```
<div>
<a href="#">first link</a>
<a href="#">second link</a>
...
</div>
```

I want to let the user click on a link and set the value of the input with the value in the link.

I guess I should do something like:

```
const input = document.getElementById('input');

document.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach(function () {
  this.onclick = function () {
    input.value = this.innerHTML();
  }
});
```

but I know that `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` doesn't return an array, so it's not possible, and I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Use a simple for loop: `var links =document.getElementsByTagName('a'); for(var i=0, n=a.length;i<n;i++)) { links[i].onclick=...`

Comment: You can make use of Array.form(), which converts a nodeList to an Array

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

The usage as per the docs:

> The HTMLCollection interface represents a generic collection (array-like object similar to arguments) of elements (in document order) and offers methods and properties for selecting from the list.

```
// document.forms is an HTMLCollection

elem1 = document.forms[0];
elem2 = document.forms.item(0);

alert(elem1 === elem2); // shows: "true"
```

This means that you should be able to treat your result like an array (including using `.length`).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Dom lists are not normal array's, so forEach won't work.
Secondly, innerHTML is not function, it's property..

The [].slice.call, can be used to convert into a normal array.

Try this below. ->

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).
forEach(function (e) {
  e.onclick = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    input.value = this.innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#">first link</a>
<a href="#">second link</a>
</div>

<input id="input" type="text">
```

Comment: You likely want to preventDefault() too to not follow the link

Comment: In this case they are empty hash bangs, so won't do anything.  But your right it's probably good practice to use preventDefault.  I'll update!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

https://jsfiddle.net/7h1a3p4x/5/

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener('click', sendData, false);
}

function sendData() {
  var input = document.getElementById("myinput");
  input.value = this.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<input id="myinput" type="text" name="name" />
<div>
  <a class="link" href="#">LINK 1</a>
  <a class="link" href="#">LINK 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It is less compatible to use addEventListener than using onclick. Also you likely want to preventDefault() to not follow the link